# Is the minimum non-countable well-ordered set compact?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a Cardinate product of 2
non-countable sets $C$ and $D$.
$$A=C \times D$$
According to the well-ordering theorem, we can define a well-order on the non-countable set $A$. We define a lexicographical order.
Take a minimum non-countable subset $B$ of $A$.$ B$ exists because in the interval $[0,x)$ of $A$, we can both find the $x$ such that $[0,x)$ countable or non-countable. Use the supremum and infimum principle(which can be proved in a well-ordered set), we can find a minimum $x$ and $[0,x)$ non-countable.

Is this kind of set compact with the order topology?

Comment: An infinite ordinal is compact in the order topology iff it's a successor ordinal.

Comment: You don't need the axiom of choice to prove there are uncountable well ordered sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if $(X, <)$ is well-ordered (say, $\min(X)=0$) and uncountable such that $[0,x)$ is countable for all $x$, the open cover

$$\mathcal{U}=\{[0,x): x \in X\}$$ cannot have a finite subcover.

For if $[0,x_1), \ldots, [0,x_N)$ were one, then define $M=\max(x_1,\ldots,x_N)) \in X$ and so $X = \bigcup_{i=1}^N [0,x_i) = [0,M)$ which contradicts the uncountability of $X$ (or we can say it doesn't cover the right hand point $M$ too).

In fact, one can show that the sup of countably many points in $X$ lies in $X$ still and $\mathcal{U}$ does not have a countable subcover either.